# Backbone fetching url and sending templateargs to javascript template

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have been learning Backbone.js and I am using it with an app on django where two photos are displayed initially: one is the main photo and other is thumbnail of next photo. I have returned json data containing the url of mainphoto and the thumbnail photo using Tastypie in the url `/api/v1/photo`. So, what I've done in Backbone is that:

```
// MODEL
var PhotoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:  '/api/v1/photo',
});

var PhotoView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: _.template($('#mainimg').html()),
initialize: function()  {
    this.render();
},
render: function(){

    var templateArgs={
        photo: this.model.get('photo')
    };
    alert(this.model.get('photo')); // this alerts undefined
    this.$el.html(this.template(templateArgs));
}
});

var photoItem = new PhotoItem({id:1});
photoItem.fetch();
var photoView = new PhotoView({model: photoItem});
```

In the django-template here is the javascript where the template argument is utilized for displaying the main photo.

```
<script type="text/template" id="mainimg">
<img class = "main-img" id="mainimgid" src = <%= photo %> alt="main photo" />
</script>
```

And this is the json data that is returned for photoItem with id=1:

```
{"next_url": "/photos/preloaded/designstyles/thumb/arabic-living(main-photo-id)-thumbnail.png",
 "parent_id": "1","photo": "/photos/preloaded/designstyles/big/arabic-bedroom.png",
 "photo_id": "1", "resource_uri": "", "tags": "set([Decimal('2'), Decimal('3')])", "type": "Homedesign"}
```

But, the image cannot be loaded. I get a javascript 404 error:

```
http://localhost:8000/undefined
```

I guess this may be due to asynchronous loading of the code. And the src for the image remains

```
<img class = "main-img" id="mainimgid" src = <%= photo %> alt="main photo" />
```

when I see on the debugging window with Chrome debugger.

What am I missing? or Where am I wrong? Can I get help?

Comment: Adding fetch call after model instantiation doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create the view without actually receiving the information from the server. You're basically passing an empty Backbone model to the view controller, that's why `model.get('photo')` is returning undefined. I'd recommend you to review basic AJAX, since that's what `Backbone.Model.fetch` does.

Asynchronous calls return immediately to avoid freezing the user interaction. That's the reason why you should not create the view until you do get the response from the server. Right solution will be something like this:

```
var photoItem = new PhotoItem({id:1}), photoView;
photoItem.fetch({
  success: function () {
    photoView = new PhotoView({model: photoItem});
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('Something bad happened!);
  }
});
```